# Error starting Celery Worker from Parent Folder

Tags: flask, heroku, celery, worker

I'm trying to deploy my Flask project on Heroku, but I'm having problems starting my Celery worker from other directory other than the `src`.

I've got my Flask `project` with the following tree:

```
.project
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── app.py
    ├── blueprints
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── error_pages.py
    │   └── profile.py
    ├── static
    │   └── ...
    └── templates
        └── ...
```

In app.py I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
import blueprints

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the config file
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')

# Initialises celery background tasks handler
celery = Celery(main=app.name, backend=app.config['REDIS_URL'], broker=app.config['REDIS_URL'],
                include=['blueprints.profile'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
app.celery = celery
```

If I am at `.project/src` and I use:

```
celery -A app.celery worker -l INFO
```

My worker starts with no problem.
But I cannot figure out how to start my worker from the root, for example.

This is how my Procfile is looking at the moment.

```
web: gunicorn --chdir ./src app:app
worker: celery -A ??????
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following `__init__.py` in my `src` directory:

```
import sys
import os

# Adding the 'src' directory to the python path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'src'))
```

And then calling the worker using:

```
celery -A src.app.celery worker -l INFO
```

Now, this is my Heroku `Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn --chdir ./src app:app
worker: celery -A src.app.celery worker
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should that code:

```
celery -A src.app.celery_file worker --loglevel=debug -B
```

(-B : for Beat) Celery config sample:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery(__name__)
celery = Celery('tasks', broker=) # rabbit,redis, ..
celery.conf.update({'CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT': ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']})
celery.conf.add_defaults(...)

celery.conf.update(CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
    'db_connect_things': {
        'task': 'application.lib.tasks.db_connect_things',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/12'),
    }})

class ContextTask(celery.Task):
...
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think that would work as well. But I would still need the __init__.py file in the 'src' directory as I have mentioned in my answer.